# New to Backbone, but when I loop through a Collection all my attributes go missing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Lets Start

```
devices = new SmartLink.Collections.DeviceMap
view = new SmartLink.Views.DeviceMap({collection: devices})
```

My Collection

```
parse: function (response) {
    console.log(response.sites);
    return response.sites;
}
```

My View

```
initialize: function (options) {
    this.collection.on('add',this.addOne,this);
    this.collection.on('reset',this.addAll,this);
    this.collection.fetch();
},

addAll: function() {
    console.log("addall");
    this.collection.forEach(this.addOne,this);
},

addOne: function(site) {
    console.log("addone");
    console.log(site);
},
```

Whats happening? 
[image: Console]

1. When parse, it prints out the response as you can see from the array of objects
2. starts addAll
3. then addOne them individually

### My Question

When I loop through each item, where is all my attributes for each item in the array?.
The only thing I see is the id's.
If I try console.log(site.name), it says undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `site.get('name')` to get the name attribute. You have to use the function `get` to get attributes from your models.